# Bot doesn't appear anywhere after uploading manifest

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to integrate a sample bot into teams. I created a manifest from Teams app studio. It uploaded successfully but didn't appear anywhere in Teams. Manifest I have inserted below. Please suggest how to fix this.

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "1e15eacc-4676-454a-8222-960a16b4e214",
    "packageName": "BOT-test",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Lalit",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "contoso96x96.png",
        "outline": "contoso20x20.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "bot-test",
        "full": "bot-test-123"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "bot-test",
        "full": "bot-test-123"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "4167f6b6-66c7-498a-92fe-4c32f5e9e19f",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}
```

Comment: Please check [Adding a bot to a team for use in channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test#adding-a-bot-to-a-team-for-use-in-channels) documentation.

Comment: Thanks It helps..I have another problem...in botframework in test tab my bot is not replying while in bot emulator it is replying....can you help in this issue....

Comment: Please follow the [Steps to see the full app in Microsoft Teams](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp#steps-to-see-the-full-app-in-microsoft-teams). Most likely you have not set the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [Adding a bot to a team for use in channels documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-test#adding-a-bot-to-a-team-for-use-in-channels). Please follow the [Steps to see the full app in Microsoft Teams](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp#steps-to-see-the-full-app-in-microsoft-teams) to try you bot in Microsoft Teams.